# Returning response from future inside a yield in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

In the following code I have a Play for Scala function with a `future` inside a `yield`. I get a compilation error `type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] required: play.api.mvc.Result`. Shouldn't I flatMap the future inside the yield to return the `Ok` response?

```
  def f1 = Future { 1 }
  def f2 = Future { 2 }

  def index = Action.async (parse.json) { request => 

        for { x1 <- f1 }
        yield {
           val f = f2
           f.flatMap { result =>
              Ok("X")
           }

        }
  }
```

Comment: Using `Future.flatMap` in the `yield` of a `Future` for-comprehension ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, when you say `flatMap` you are saying that the result returned in the function is a `Future[T]`, which in your example it returns a `Result`, so just using a `map` would work, but is not super idiomatic as you have to `flatten` as you wind up with a `Future[Future[Result]]`:

```
(for { x1 <- f1 } yield {
    val f = f2
    f.map( result =>
       Ok("X")
    )
}).flatten
```

What is more idiomatic is to use a for comprehension for the whole thing:

```
for {
  x1 <- f1
  x2 <- f2
} yield {
  Ok("X")
}
```

Comment: problem is that I need to run three futures (f1, f1a, f1b) in the for comprehension and with the result I need to run another future f2 (that I have in the yield section). So I end up with a future inside a yield. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to run that future inside the yield? It sounds like it could live outside the yield unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Just add `x1b <- f1b` inside the `for` block then write `yield x1b`.